# Incomplete set of least cost paths in R

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, cost-path

In R, generate a conductance raster with "square" cells, derive the centroid of each cell, and compute the least cost paths (LCPs) between each pair of centroids through any of the possible commands from the [`leastcostpath`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/leastcostpath/leastcostpath.pdf) package. Finally, compute the LCP density by cell via the same package.

It turns out that this procedure ends up systematically **missing** some of the possible LCPs, so that the resulting density computation is biased. The reason why this happens is that commands such as `create_FETE_lcps` or `create_lcp` systematically miss to identify some ties in the possible LCPs that connect a given pair of endpoints.

The minimal working example hereby illustrates this problem and shows two examples in which more LCPs should appear for two given endpoints, while only one is identified (these examples are labeled as "Combination 8" and "Combination 14").

What is the **potential cause** of this problem?

At this point I am unable to tell. Initially, I suspected that the issue could arise due to the chosen CRS projection or, more broadly, because raster pixels are not perfectly square and/or of equal area. So, I have tried different CRS projections (which you find commented in the code) to guarantee equal distance, equal area, or both. But none of these attempts solve the problem.

Notably, I cannot rely on the `passage` command from the [`gdistance`](https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2014-12-09/web/packages/gdistance/vignettes/gdistance.pdf) package, because it does not offer the same possibility of control that I need for the task at stake. For example, the command `passage` counts the number of passages but not the lengths involved.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
# Packages ----
library(sp)
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(gdistance)
library(gtools)
library(leastcostpath)

# Create conductance surface ----
nr <- 3
nc <- 3
conductance.r <- raster(
  nrows = nr,
  ncols = nc,
  xmn = 0.0 - nc/2,
  xmx = 0.0 + nc/2,
  ymn = 0.0 - nr/2,
  ymx = 0.0 + nr/2,
  crs = "EPSG:4087", #WGS 84 / World Equidistant Cylindrical
  # crs = "EPSG:6933", #WGS 84 / NSIDC EASE-Grid 2.0 Global
  # crs = "EPSG:3395", #WGS 84 / World Mercator
  vals = c( 1, 1, 1,
            1, 1/3, 1,
            1, 1, 1)
)

# Pixel info derived from the conductance raster ----
pix.idx.na <- is.na(conductance.r) # NA pixels
pix.num.valid <- freq(pix.idx.na, value = 0)
pix.num.tot <- ncell(conductance.r)

# Polygons and centroids derived from raster cells ----
pgn.inn <- rasterToPolygons(conductance.r,
                            n = 8,
                            digits = 12,
                            na.rm = T)
pgn.inn$cell <- Which(!is.na(conductance.r), cells = T)
ctr.inn <- gCentroid(pgn.inn, byid = T)
ctr.inn$cell <- Which(!is.na(conductance.r), cells = T)

# From conductance raster to transition layer ----
conductance.tr <- gdistance::transition(
  conductance.r,
  transitionFunction = mean,
  directions = 8,
  symm = T
)
conductance.tr <- gdistance::geoCorrection(conductance.tr,
                                           type = "c",
                                           multpl = F)
image(transitionMatrix(conductance.tr),
      main = "Transition layer")

# List of all possible combinations of endpoints ----
ncombs <- choose(prod(dim(conductance.r)[1:2]), 2)
options(expressions = 5 * 1e5)
combs <- t(combn(x = ctr.inn$cell, m = 2, simplify = T))

# Cycle of FETE LCPs ----
lcp.fete.list <- list()
endpts.list <- list()
writeLines("Cycle:")
pb = txtProgressBar(min = 0, 
                    max = ncombs, 
                    initial = 0,
                    width = 60,
                    style = 3)
for (i in seq(1, ncombs)) {
  
  # Completion percentage
  setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
  
  # Combination of points
  id <- is.element(ctr.inn$cell,combs[i,]) 
  endpts <- ctr.inn[id ,]
  
  # FETE LCPs
  invisible(
    capture.output(
      lcp.fete <- create_FETE_lcps(conductance.tr,
                                   endpts,
                                   cost_distance = T,
                                   parallel = F) %>%
        st_as_sf() %>%
        st_transform(st_crs(conductance.r)) %>%
        as("Spatial")
    )
  )
  lcp.fete@data$length <- gLength(lcp.fete, byid = T)
  
  # Plot key LCPs
  if (i == 8 | i == 14){
    par(mar = c(0,0,2,0),
        oma = c(0,0,2,0))
    plot(
      main = paste("Combination",i),
      conductance.r,
      colNA = NA,
      axes = F,
      box = F,
      legend = F
    )
    plot(pgn.inn, border = "white", lwd = 0.2, add = T)
    plot(
      lcp.fete,
      col = "black",
      lwd = 2,
      axes = F,
      add = T
    )
    plot(
      endpts,
      pch = 16,
      cex = 1,
      col = "black",
      axes = F,
      add = T
    )
  }
  
  # Append lines and points
  lcp.fete.list[[i]] <- lcp.fete
  endpts.list[[i]] <- endpts
  
}
close(pb) # close progress bar

# Compute density ----
x <- do.call(rbind, lcp.fete.list)
density.r <- create_lcp_density(
  lcps = x,
  raster = conductance.r,
  rescale = F,
  rasterize_as_points = T
)
density.r[pix.idx.na] <- NA
crs(density.r) <- crs(pgn.inn)
par(mar = c(0,0,0,2),
    oma = c(0,0,0,2))
plot(density.r,
     axes = F,
     box = F,
     legend.args = list(text = "Density (m)", line = 1, font = 2))
text(density.r)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, thank you for using the R package *leastcostpath*! And thank you for flagging this issue. I'll be sure to rectify it within the package when I have time!

From my testing the issue is that the *create_lcp()* function uses the function *shortest_paths()* from igraph. This only returns one least-cost path irrespective of whether there are multiple paths that have equal weight:

shortest_paths() calculates a single shortest path (i.e. the path itself, not just its length) between the source vertex given in from, to the target vertices given in to. shortest_paths() uses breadth-first search for unweighted graphs and Dijkstra's algorithm for weighted graphs. The latter only works if the edge weights are non-negative.

One way to fix this is to use *all_shortest_paths* function from *igraph*. This will return all LCPs that have equal lowest-cost.

You can modify the *create_lcp()* function to something like this:

```
lcp_graph <- igraph::all_shortest_paths(cm_graph, from = from_cell, 
                                        to = to_cell, mode = "out")

lcps <- lapply(lcp_graph$res, FUN = function(i) {
  lcp_xy <- terra::xyFromCell(cs_rast, as.integer(i))
  lcp <- sf::st_sf(geometry = sf::st_sfc(sf::st_linestring(lcp_xy)), 
                   crs = x$crs)
  return(lcp)
})
```

toy example below:

```
library(sf)
library(terra)
library(leastcostpath)

# Create toy cost raster with projected coordinates
nr <- 5
nc <- 3
m <- matrix(
  data = c(1,NA,NA,
           1,1,NA,
           2,3,1,
           1,1,1,
           NA,1,NA),
  nrow = nr,
  ncol = nc,
  byrow = T)

m <- 1/m

cost.r <- rast(m,crs = "EPSG:3003")
plot(cost.r)
#plotted the values in the spatRaster so we can visualise
text(cost.r)

pgn.inn <- as.polygons(cost.r,
                       aggregate = F,
                       na.rm = T,
                       na.all = T)
pgn.inn <- st_as_sf(pgn.inn)

# Cell centroids
ctr.inn <- st_centroid(pgn.inn)

# Pick two endpoints
endpts <- ctr.inn[c(1,4) ,1]

# Create conductance matrix via <create_cs>
conductanceMatrix <- create_cs(
  x = cost.r,
  neighbours = 8)

create_lcp <- function (x, origin, destination, cost_distance = FALSE, check_locations = FALSE) 
{
  if (check_locations) {
    check_locations(x, origin)
    check_locations(x, destination)
  }
  cs_rast <- terra::rast(nrow = x$nrow, ncol = x$ncol, xmin = x$extent[1], 
                         xmax = x$extent[2], ymin = x$extent[3], ymax = x$extent[4], 
                         crs = x$crs)
  from_coords <- get_coordinates(origin)
  to_coords <- get_coordinates(destination)
  from_cell <- terra::cellFromXY(cs_rast, from_coords[1, , 
                                                      drop = FALSE])
  to_cell <- terra::cellFromXY(cs_rast, to_coords)
  cm_graph <- igraph::graph_from_adjacency_matrix(x$conductanceMatrix, 
                                                  mode = "directed", weighted = TRUE)
  igraph::E(cm_graph)$weight <- (1/igraph::E(cm_graph)$weight)
  lcp_graph <- igraph::all_shortest_paths(cm_graph, from = from_cell, 
                                          to = to_cell, mode = "out")
  lcps <- lapply(lcp_graph$res, FUN = function(i) {
    lcp_xy <- terra::xyFromCell(cs_rast, as.integer(i))
    lcp <- sf::st_sf(geometry = sf::st_sfc(sf::st_linestring(lcp_xy)), 
                     crs = x$crs)
    return(lcp)
  })
  lcps <- do.call(rbind, lcps)
  if (!is.function(x$costFunction)) {
    lcps$costFunction <- x$costFunction
  }
  else if (is.function(x$costFunction)) {
    lcps$costFunction <- deparse(body(x$costFunction)[[2]])
  }
  lcps$fromCell <- from_cell
  lcps$toCell <- to_cell
  if (cost_distance) {
    lcps$cost <- NA
    for (i in 1:length(to_cell)) {
      lcps$cost[i] <- igraph::distances(graph = cm_graph, 
                                        v = from_cell, to = to_cell[i], mode = "out", 
                                        algorithm = "dijkstra")
    }
  }
  if (sum(to_cell %in% from_cell) != 0) {
    message(sum(to_cell %in% from_cell), " least-cost paths could not be calculated from origin to destination as these share the same location")
  }
  lcps <- lcps[!is.na(sf::st_is_valid(lcps)), ]
  if (inherits(origin, "SpatVector") & inherits(destination, 
                                                "SpatVector")) {
    lcps <- terra::vect(lcps)
  }
  return(lcps)
}

lcps <- create_lcp(x = conductanceMatrix, origin = endpts[1,], destination = endpts[2,])
lcps

plot(cost.r)
#plotted the values in the spatRaster so we can visualise
text(cost.r)
plot(terra::vect(lcps), add = T)
plot(terra::vect(lcps)[1,], add = T, col = "red")
plot(terra::vect(lcps)[2,], add = T, col = "blue")
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for the time you have put into this package and in answering my questions. Is there a way to reproduce exactly the same output as in my MWE but without resorting to `raster` and `gdistance`? Naturally, this relates to my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77975556/incoherent-least-cost-path).

Comment: Since I have to compute LCPs correcting for distance on the transition layer, I am forced to use version 1.8.7 of `leastcostpath`. In that version, LCPs are identified via `gdistance::shortestpath`, which indeed seems to fail identifying all the ties in some cases while managing in others. At this point, I am unable to tell what could be driving this behavior.

Comment: After trying out with `gdistance::shortestpath`, I can confirm that it suffices to substitute the current `get.shortest.paths()` with `all_shortest_paths()`. This also entails some minimal variations in the `create_FETE_lcps` and `create_lcp` commands, to accomodate the possibly higher number of spatial lines that enter the output.